# Laravel insert into a model with multiple relationships

Tags: orm, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I'm trying to do this with eloquent http://paste.laravel.com/Fnq

But I fail at the second statement because the first attempted an insert without waiting.
Anyway to insert into a model with multiple relationships?

Comment: you could try push http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#insert-update-delete

Comment: thats for non related models.

Comment: please elaborate your question? and provide some more code then just 2 lines. And if you want to save data to multiple relationship thn push is meant for this only

Comment: can you write an answer on how to use push() in the context of saving two relationships on the same model at the same time so there isnt a foreign key error?

Comment: can you give some more details, What exactly are you trying to do? some model codes? etc

Comment: http://paste.laravel.com/Fnq

Comment: You need to return.  `return $this->hasOne('Foo');`